# AWS S3 Files Cross Account Not Decrypting

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-cli, amazon-kms

I’m currently trying to get access S3 files in another VPC, and I am able to successfully. But when the files come in, they are all still encrypted.

I have machines in VPC A that are trying to read S3 files in VPC B. The files are server side encrypted when they go to the bucket in VPC B. I successfully assume role and have files coming from the S3 bucket in VPC B to VPC A. However, the files in my machines in VPC A should be coming in as json, but instead appear to still be encrypted.

When I have machines in VPC A reading server side encrypted files from an S3 bucket in VPC A, then I don’t have this issue.  The files seem to be automatically decrypted.

The command via CLI command looks similar to this (in VPC A):

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn ROLEARN --role-session-name s3-cloudtrail-access
aws s3 cp s3://LOCATIONOFFILE.json.gz test.json.gz --profile crossaccountrole
```

With the Java SDK it’s like this (in VPC A):

```
ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
AWSSecurityTokenService securityTokenService = new AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient(config);
AssumeRoleResult assumeRoleResult = securityTokenService.assumeRole(new AssumeRoleRequest()
    .withRoleArn(roleArn).withDurationSeconds(3600)
    .withRoleSessionName("s3-cloudtrail-access"));
Credentials stsCredentials = assumeRoleResult.getCredentials();
System.out.println("stsCredentials: " + stsCredentials);
AWSSessionCredentials tempCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
    stsCredentials.getAccessKeyId(), stsCredentials.getSecretAccessKey(),
    stsCredentials.getSessionToken()
);
AmazonS3 tempClient = new AmazonS3Client(tempCredentials, config);
tempClient.getObject(
    new GetObjectRequest(horizBucketName, horizFileNameInS3),
    new File("/home/ec2-user/test-horiz.json.gz")
);
```

Any ideas as to how I can make sure that the files come over between VPCs decrypted?

Best,
Keren

Answer (score 1):

Just kidding, I have figured it out. The files were json.gz files which means I needed to unzip them. The code above works for getting S3 files cross account if anyone wants to use it :)